# RGL: multiple polygon3d that can go through

Tags: r, shiny, polygons, rgl

I am developping a Shiny application and I am looking for a way to force polygons to be drawing. I am using RGL for my 3D scatterplot and I want to be able to draw polygons between some points that share the same information.

My problem is that, apparently, if a polygon3d (P1) already exists, a new polygon3d (P2) can't be drawn if P2 will go through P1. I can disable fill parameter, of course, and I have the segments, in thin lines, for each polygons, but I want to make the polygons more highlighted, by filling them if possible. How can I fill or highlight my polygons?

**Edit:**

Here are two screenshots.

1) try in polygon3d with option fill = F. Here, I can see all the segments that delimitate my polygons.

http://norore.fr/images/stackoverflow/R_polygons3d_fillF.png

2) try in polygon3d with option fill = T. Here, I can only see few polygons. The lost polygons generate the followed error:

```
Warning in max(-coeffs[dn, 2]/(coeffs[dn, 1] - coeffs[dn, 2])) :
  aucun argument pour max ; -Inf est renvoyé
Warning in max(-coeffs[up, 1]/(coeffs[up, 2] - coeffs[up, 1])) :
  aucun argument pour max ; -Inf est renvoyé
Warning in max(-coeffs[up, 1]/(coeffs[up, 2] - coeffs[up, 1])) :
  aucun argument pour max ; -Inf est renvoyé
Error in processOutside(i) : Cannot triangulate polygon
```

http://norore.fr/images/stackoverflow/R_polygons3d_fillT.png

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can't be drawn".   Post an example, and a screenshot of the result, and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: I just post 2 pictures. One without filled polygons, and one with filled polygons. I also add more informations. Sorry, I'm not sure if I can paste sample data as they are still confident.

Comment: The message says that the function was unable to triangulate the polygon.  Generally it can only do so for non-degenerate, non-self-intersecting, planar polygons.  Yours may not meet those conditions.  You might be able to use the `deldir()` function in the `deldir` package if the points form a surface, but otherwise, you're going to have to limit yourself to triangles and quadrilaterals.